# How to make a multithreading for my private function in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I try to develop software for analyzing websites. I done everything but my problem is if I have like 1000 websites link and I need to make it in multithreading to be more faster than the normal, so how can I give my software threads like 100 to analyzing 100 website in the same time.

```
public static int threads = 100;

static void Main(string[] args) {
    Console.Title = "SearchSites v0.1";
    wordlist = File.ReadLines("test.txt");
    json_callAsync("https://google.com");
    json_callAsync("https://twitter.com");
    json_callAsync("https://yahoo.com");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

`json_callAsync();` is my function to analyzing the site and `threads = 100` is how many website run in the same time.

Another problem is how I know if all websites in test.txt it has been completed to stop the threads and the software.

I still don't try any methods or anything.

Comment: **Bold** or CAPITAL letters are to emphasize a word, but on whole sentences it is like screaming at us. And just ask the question and skip anything that does not belong to the question. We do not care if it is your first application. We will try to answer you as we do for any other asking here :o)

Comment: Could you include in the question the definition (signature) of the `json_callAsync` method? Also please mention the .NET platform that you are targeting (.NET Framework / .NET 7 etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `Parallel` holds methods that help you using multithreading. For your needs, the method `ForEach` might help you.

```
string[] urls = new string[] { "https://google.com", "https://twitter.com", "https://yahoo.com" };
Parallel.ForEach(urls, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 100 }, url => json_callAsync(url));
```

Comment: `json_callAsync` sounds to be an async method and if you will have more than 100 request in parallel

Comment: thanks so much it work very good with my async method

Comment: If `json_callAsync` is an `async` method, then this does not work. See [dotnet fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5L0pKm), because `Parallel.ForEach` does not wait until that async method is completed.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a list of url sites:

```
List<String> urlList = new List<String>();
urlList.Add("https://google.com");
urlList.Add("https://twitter.com");
urlList.Add("https://yahoo.com");
...
```

Then use [Task.Run()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-7.0) for parallel execution:

```
for (int i=0;i<urlList.Count;i++)
{
     Task.Run(() => json_callAsync(urlList[i]));
}
```

Comment: that does not limit it to max 100 tasks in parallel

Comment: i need something be more advanced to avoid high cpu or any problem like that, cuz i will analyzing over 10 millions sites with thread over 300